# Unreliable Scrolling Behavior with Logitech M560

Tags: mouse

When I'm scrolling with my Mouse (Logitech Wireless Mouse M560) I get stuck sometimes. It works perfectly most of the times but then suddenly just stops to scroll completly and only after a few more "scrollclicks" it will go back to normal. And if thats not even strange enough, it will get stuck again reliably if I scroll back to that same position. The problem seems to be somewhere really deep because I checked the events coming from my mouse, while scrolling and they also resemble that behavior.

I've already tried a bunch of stuff like installing imwheel and running it, overriding the MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_ANGLE because I thought it could be the missalignment of that (but it isn't).

...

I just tested my mouse on another Laptop, I guess this will be a slightly different post now...

Comment: [From Review] Voted to leave this open, as the fix will be useful for future searchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post a question like this you should always ask where the problem could be and check everything you know. So I suddenly thought, what if my battery is almost empty, so I switched it (same behavior) then I thought, lets try my mouse on an other computer on Windows to really be sure that its not my hardware. And then there was my facepalm moment. I had already written this question to post it and found out that its just my mouse being broken.

This is really silly and I can't stop laughing at myself for spending 3 hours on this already to find out my mouse is broken. So take that and check your hardware!

I hope this will help atleast one person. That would mean the world to me after these hours of searching...

EDIT:
I just repaired my mouse. As it turns out there was dust inside the scroll wheel that would on occasion get caught by it and block the photocell. Initially I thought of a problem like this, but hence it didn't occur on every turn I discarded that Idea. Oh how wrong I was there...

Comment: Welcome to the world of optical scrollwheels ;-)